# pipe (vertical bar) symbol in function

Tags: functions, physics, mathematical-physics, education, symbolic-computation

could you please explain me what pipe symbols | means in bellow's function?!
$$
force = -R_B * D(v_a^B|v_a^B|)*c_D  
$$
where we have introduced a notation $ D(b) = diag(b_x; b_y; b_z) $for a vector $b$.

Comment: Hard to tell without the context. What is $v_a^B$? If it is some sort of a vector, could $|v_a^B|$ be its *norm*? If it is a number - could it be its *modulus*?

Comment: $v_a^B$ speed on $a$ axis in Body frame, $R_B$ is rotational matrix, $c_D$ is coefficient

Comment: @StinkingBishop

Comment: Then $|\ |$ is the absolute value. That way $|v|$ is a scalar, and $v|v|$ is a vector in the direction of $v$, with components $\left(v_x\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2},v_y\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2},v_z\sqrt{v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2}\right)$

Comment: @Andrei thanks for your help